# Front-Door Adjustment formula: confusing notation

Tags: causality, notation, sum

Pearl et al. ["Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer"](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Causal+Inference+in+Statistics%3A+A+Primer-p-9781119186847) (2016) p. 69 Theorem 3.4.1 provides the Front-Door Adjustment formula:
$$
P(y | \text{do}(X = x)) = \sum_z P(z | x) \sum_{x'} P(y|x', z)P(x').
$$
Does it mean
$$
P(y | \text{do}(X = x)) = \sum_z \left[ P(z | x) \sum_{x'} \left\{ P(y|x', z)P(x') \right\} \right]
$$
or
$$
P(y | \text{do}(X = x)) = \left[ \sum_z P(z | x) \right]\cdot \left[ \sum_{x'} \left\{ P(y|x', z)P(x')  \right\} \right]?
$$

Comment: The last expression is not allowed, because $P(y|x',z)$ has $z$ in it, but that term has fallen out of scope of the $z$ summation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means
$$
P(y|\text{do}(X=x)) = \sum_z \left[ P(z|x) \sum_{x'} \left\{ P(y|x',z) P(x') \right\} \right].
$$
This can be seen from equation (3.15) on p. 68 which is
$$
P(y|\text{do}(X=x)) = \sum_z \sum_{x'} \left\{ P(y|x',z) P(x') P(z|x) \right\}
$$
and can be rearranged to be
$$
P(y|\text{do}(X=x)) = \sum_z \sum_{x'} \left\{ P(z|x) P(y|x',z) P(x') \right\},
$$
the latter ordering of conditional probabilities corresponding to the ordering in the equation at the top of this answer.

Comment: Right. $x'$ is just a dummy variable, and does not show up in the $P(z|x),$ so that that term can move in or out of the second sum with impunity.