# Front-door adjustment formula: difficulty in reconcile the two formula

Tags: causality

In *The Book Of Why*, the author gives two formulas related to the front-door adjustment formula.

On page 227 (formula 7.1), the front-door adjustment is given by
$$P(Y|do(X)) = \sum_zP(Z=z|X)\sum_xP(Y|X=x,Z=z)P(X=x)$$

On page 236 (figure 7.4), the front-door adjustment is given by
$$P(c|do(s)) = \sum_{s'}\sum_tP(c|t,s')P(s')P(t|s)$$
Or, after aligning the notation
$$P(Y|do(X)) = \sum_{X'}\sum_ZP(Y|z,x')P(x')P(z|x)$$

I have read this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/458046/front-door-adjustment-formula-confusing-notation), and understand that the final formula can be expressed as:
$$P(Y|do(X)) = \sum_Z\sum_{X'}P(z|x)P(Y|z,x')P(x')$$
which is the same as formula 7.1.

But I am not sure why $x$ becomes $x'$ in the last formula?

and secondly since $\sum_{X'}\sum_ZP(Y|z,x')P(x')P(z|x)$ is actually a multiplication inside, can I write it as $\sum_Z\sum_{X'}P(Y|z,x')P(x')P(z|x)$?

Comment: x' is the intrevention observed in the data, x is the intervention of interest, the do(x). See also Derivation of front door adjustment without intervention on the mediator https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.20278347.v1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: Why does $x$ becomes $x'$ in the last formula?

Answer: $x$ does not "become" $x'$ in the last formula. $x'$ is a variable of summation, and hence a "dummy" variable. It has no scope outside the summation. You could just as easily write
$$P(Y|\operatorname{do}(X)) = \sum_Z\sum_{X}P(z|x)P(Y|z,\xi)P(\xi).$$
On the other hand, the $x$ shows up on both sides of the equation, and definitely has scope inside and outside the summation. So the $x$ is a particular value of the random variable $X,$ whereas the $x'$ is a dummy variable that ranges over all the possible values of $X.$ Here's what I would regard as the clearest way to write the equation:
$$P(Y=y|\operatorname{do}(X=x)) = \sum_{Z=z}\sum_{X=x'}P(Z=z|X=x)P(Y=y|Z=z,X=x')P(X=x').$$
This is clunkier, I admit.

Question 2: ... since $\sum_{X'}\sum_ZP(Y|z,x')P(x')P(z|x)$ is actually a multiplication inside, can I write it as $\sum_Z\sum_{X'}P(Y|z,x')P(x')P(z|x)$?

Answer: Yes, absolutely. In finite summations, you can always reverse the order of summation - a direct result of the commutativity of addition. In many integral settings you can also reverse the order of integration, though there are some situations in which you can't. [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) provides sufficient conditions for reversing the order of integration.